# Regex that allows PascalCased with one or more consecutive uppercase letters and numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to check user input for PascalCased names and this works, but I would like to also allow one or more consecutive upperCase letters eg. UNOrganization and also allow numbers in between eg. A2BOrganization.

So all of the following should be allowed: ABCWord, A3BWord, OtherWord, Word3, Word3AB (last unlikely but if possible fine)

```
  if (value.match(/^[A-Z][a-z]+(?:[A-Z][a-z]+)*$/)) {
    //logic here
  }
```

Regex is a little beyond me and the logic to parse the strings would be too long for my needs and I know this can be done in a one-liner with regex so hopefully someone more savvy can help me.

Comment: You may try: `/^[A-Z\d]+[a-z]+(?:[A-Z\d]+[a-z]*)*$/`

Comment: I think so (??) in my case I want to allow acronyms in the name string and sometimes they include numbers too

Comment: Do you accept `"Aa1a"`?

Comment: all the time they would be words that have a meaning so that prob won't be an use case

Comment: correct, I believe someone has a solution tho that works for me, thank you so much tho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
^[A-Z]+[a-z]*(?:\d*(?:[A-Z]+[a-z]*)?)*$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/geECc8/1)

If you require at least one lowercase letter in the input string:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])[A-Z]+[a-z]*(?:\d*(?:[A-Z]+[a-z]*)?)*$
```

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                         (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z]                    any character of: 'a' to 'z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [A-Z]+                   any character of: 'A' to 'Z' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-z]*                   any character of: 'a' to 'z' (0 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d*                      digits (0-9) (0 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [A-Z]+                   any character of: 'A' to 'Z' (1 or
                               more times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [a-z]*                   any character of: 'a' to 'z' (0 or
                               more times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: I guess it could be possible but not very likely in my case.

Comment: @Amessihel Yes, there is `*`, have a look at that expression part: `(?:\d*(?:[A-Z]+[a-z]*)?)*`. See the last `*`.

Answer (score 2):

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])[A-Z]\d*[a-z]*(([A-Z\d]*[A-Z]|[A-Z][A-Z\d]*|\d+$)[a-z]*)*$/
```

seems to fit your requirements. See tests below.

The idea is to start with a capital letter followed by an optional digit and zero or more lowercase letters. Then enter the main group repeated zero or more times. This group matches one or more capital letters or digits followed by zero or more lowercase letters. The alternation handles allowing digits at the end and disallowing lone digits sandwiched between two lowercase characters.

```js
const pat = /^(?=.*[a-z])[A-Z]\d*[a-z]*(([A-Z\d]*[A-Z]|[A-Z][A-Z\d]*|\d+$)[a-z]*)*$/;

const tests = [
  "UNOrganization",
  "A2BOrganization", 
  "ABCWord", 
  "A3BWord", 
  "OtherWord", 
  "Word3", 
  "Word3AB",
  "a",
  "A",
  "Aa",
  "aA",
  "AAA",
  "aaa",
  "9A",
  "A4",
  "A4a",
  "AaA",
  "AaAa",
  "Aa1",
  "AaA1",
  "Aa1a",
  "",
];
const len = 2 + Math.max(...tests.map(e => e.length));
tests.forEach(e => 
  console.log(`${`'${e}'`.padStart(len)} => ${pat.test(e)}`)
);
```

Comment: I wouldn't allow starting with lower case tho, I believe that's camelCase but other cases work, so for me this allow some things I don't want.

Comment: Which things does this allow that you don't want? I disallow starting with a lowercase letter.

Comment: I believe the above solution will work perfectly for my case so no need to edit tho I appreciate your time!

Comment: Nice to know but I'd prefer to have an answer that actually matches your spec so that it's a useful resource for future visitors. I don't mind editing.

Comment: correct, not starting with lowercase, minimum one lowercase letter tho, no numbers in between lowercase (for my case this would not happen as the words have to have a meaning), not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Another pattern:

```
^[A-Z]+[A-Za-z]*(?:[0-9]+(?:[A-Z]+[A-Za-z]*)*)*$
```

- `[A-Z]+[A-Za-z]*`: At least one capital letter optionally followed a sequence of letters of any case, ...
- `(?: ... )*`: ... optionally followed by a sequence of :

  - `[0-9]+`: one or more digit...
  - `(?: ... )*`: optionally followed by a sequence of :

    - `[A-Z]+[A-Za-z]*`: at least one capital letter optionally followed a sequence of letters of any case

[Regex101.com working examples](https://regex101.com/r/tbj2dj/1) (replaced `^` and `$` by word delimiters `\b`).